# "NOAUTH Authentication required" error is seen sometimes

Tags: java, tomcat, redis

`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: NOAUTH Authentication required.; 
nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: NOAUTH Authentication required.`

The above error occurs sometimes when I try to login into my application.

My set up is:

- Tomcat is the application server
- Redis is used to maintain session.

After restarting the redis, it starts working fine for a day or two after which the error is occurring again.

Please help in resolving this permanently..

Comment: You are leaving your Redis server unprotected and open to the world. This could lead to a world of pain, including having the server exploited (see here for more details: http://antirez.com/news/96). Apparently, someone is connecting to your unprotected Redis database after you restart and sets a password. This could be a white hat hacker's way to protect you, but possibly it is the work of a person with ill intents.

You should **really** protect your Redis server - at the very least use a password.

Comment: Thanks for you advice.. Is it possible to access my redis server without the server password.. ? redis is running in a password protected server..

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your Redis password after using pool.
I was having some problem with AUTH as well and then saw someone having similar problem with Lettuce by setting redis password before using pool.
Change the order, once you set your factory to use pool, then set the password.
The solution worked fine for me.
[Link to similar problem with Lettuce](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/issues/327)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable remote access with the line

```
bind 127.0.0.1
```

A lot of redis servers are being attacked with antirez's security vulnerability [post](http://antirez.com/news/96). Read it carefully and secure your setup. Unfortunately some redis installations come with these security vulnerabilities.